# Proximity prompt cooldown

Tags: roblox

How could I add a cooldown to my Proximity Prompt to press it again?

press key, after wait any seconds for press it again

Comment: Heyo, when asking questions on StackOverflow, the expectation is that you've tried doing some research on how to fix it first. Then, you share the code that you tried and tell us what isn't working. If you don't know where to start, consider reading the documentation for [ProximityPrompts](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ProximityPrompt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a matter of using the function `ProximityPrompt.Triggered` and then disabling the prompt for a certain period of time before reenabling it again.

```
local prompt = script.Parent

prompt.Triggered:Connect(function()
    print("triggered") --Action
    
    prompt.Enabled = false
    wait(5) --However long you want
    prompt.Enabled = true
end)
```